# Negative feedback but the other person is unaware of issue

Tags: management, manager, feedback, people-management, conflict-resolution

This is a question for managers.
When someone in your team approaches you to complain/give negative feedback about a team member does it matter to you, and how you handle things, if they have not discussed anything with the other team member?

Is that a sign of an interpersonal conflict or is it something else?

How do you decide if the situation can not be salvaged.
To connect it with my previous point, would it be correct to assume that since there has not been any discussion of the issue with the other person it can not be salvaged?
My question is purely theorical trying to get different points of view on how conflict is handled

**Update**
Lets assume the feedback is that person A, is pushing a lot for her opinion in discussions or that person A is too direct in interactions. Ie things that are subjective by nature. Not something such as odors or lack of work etc

Comment: We don't answer theoretical questions on here. As per the FAQ, it has to be an actual problem you're having. Besides, your question is too broad. It could really be about anything: body odor, sexual comments, tardiness, bad work attitude, etc. Or it could just be that the complainant thinks this is your responsibility to handle as a manager. And yes, perhaps we could write a 300 page book dealing with every possible scenario, but that would just be too much work.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: what if it is mainly clash of personalities but nothing performance related. I was thinking going to the manager is escalation and possibly breaks team spirit because the person did not try to discuss as professional. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense, because if it was just a clash of personalities, why would this be any of your concern? "to complain/give negative feedback about a team member" Again, you haven't told us what this negative feedback was about.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Sure, that's true... but the reverse is also true.  Some issues it's reasonable, or even wise, to raise your concerns with your manager right away.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere:i made an update. Does it help?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk:i made an update, does it help?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere:i agree with the whining part but how do you handle that? Do you tell them to address it with the coworker?

Comment: Have you faced this issue? If so can you put the details in, to avoid it being just a hypothetical question with a million possible answers

Comment: @Smith, The example given is still pretty vague. But personally, that wouldn't be my problem. I can't fight their battle for them. They have to discuss those issues with them, not me. With that said, if the person they're complaining about is really a jerk (and you've confirmed those allegations). It may be worth considering replacing that jerk down the line, when the opportunity presents itself. Jerks can be toxic to a workplace.

Answer (score 2):

Do you as a manager or your management or project management style provide *any* means to discuss that, or do you just leave it to the concerned party to somehow miraculously solve it by themselves?

Some project management approaches (mainly the "agile" one's) have feedback mechanisms and even trained personal where and by whom this can be handled. Many traditional approaches are basically just shrugging your shoulders and leaving it to the workers, with results that are... well about as successful as  you would think a such non-action method is.

Your workers are trained in many things for their job, but chances are that interpersonal conflict resolution is not one of them.

On the positive side, one of them asked for your help. It is your job to provide an optimal work environment to them, so you should try.

From my experience, subjective issues (Alice is too subjective, Alice is too assertive, Alice is too...) are not solved by telling Alice to be less of anything. It's unfair to both the one with the perceived problem, because they don't perceive it and so would have a hard time changing it even if they wanted, and the one perceiving the problem, because it will become clear that they told you and they will be seen as "the snitch" or "the one who runs to management to solve their problems".

If you hear a problem description, listen carefully and then find a way for a better solution for everyone. So if Alice always goes first in discussions and dominates the table with their opinion, do not say "Bob feels Bob should go first". Listen to Bobs problem and then come up with a solution that is fair for everybody and solves the problem. Maybe you rotate on who goes first. Or draw numbers? Sometimes Alice goes first, sometimes Bob, sometimes Charlie. But find a solution where Alice does not feel singled out and it is not obvious Bob brought this up.

If there is no neutral, fair solution and you *have* to tell Alice to act differently, do it as their boss and with *your* observations. Don't use Bob as a shield or Bob's information as your source. Say "**I** observed that we don't get a lot of different opinions when Alice goes first, so **I** want Bob to go first this time." You are the manager, you made the decision. The bucket stops with you.

Comment: `do it as their boss and with your observations` what if the manager does not have such observations or even consider it is an issue? How this can happen then? `It is your job to provide an optimal work environment to them, so you should try` if only one person has the issue? That is why I originally wondered if it breaks the team spirit a behavior that ignores the team member and escalates to the manager

Comment: Well if you did not observe it yourself, then you need to put yourself in a position to be able to do so. If you don't see it as a problem, your subordinate still sees it as a problem and you need to decide what to do about it. Maybe the solution is to show the person that they are objectively wrong, or give them training to be more assertive... but that's all speculation because your question is so vague. Sorry.

Comment: I noticed that you did not mention at all the idea of asking them why they did not bring this up to their colleague. Is it related to the assertive training suggestion?

Comment: Not really. It just doesn't actually lead to a solution. There is no answer to that question that would solve your or their problem.

Comment: I can see that the person complaining can be demotivated by inaction. What about the impact on the other person though that are completely unaware that the issue is there?

Comment: I don't know. Depends on what action you take and whether they perceive that as a problem at all. For example, making people take turns going first, I don't see why someone would perceive that as a problem. Especially if you don't tell anyone it's to make Alice be less dominant.

Comment: But i your example you assume there is an objective behavior to address. What if Bob is too "sensitive" and has a history of easily complaining about things that the rest of the team including the manager think are non issue?

Comment: See, this is why we don't accept theoretical questions. They never end. I cannot go down every single "but what if" rabbit hole with you. If you have an actual issue with a subordinate being too sensitive about another subordinates behaviour, ask that question.

Comment: fair enough. I did find your answers helpful by the way

Answer (score 1):

> When someone in your team approaches you to complain/give negative feedback about a team member does it matter to you

Bringing issues to a manager does two things.

It formalises the issue, it now needs to be documented and analysed by a third party (the manager) which is an escalation.

It does matter to the manager because once formalised it's their duty to resolve the issue or dismiss it.

, and how you handle things, if they have not discussed anything with the other team member?

Any variables in the situation can impact on how the manager handles it.

Comment: The does it matter question was about the fact they have not made any effort to discuss with their coworker

Comment: @smith I know, it's just a variable like anything else, so of course it has an impact.